# Create Database - PostgreSQL - Tom Aratyn's book

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am reading the **Tom Aratyn Book - Building Django 2.0 web application**. I am on a basic level.

Before migrating my app to the database, he asks to create a database for our Django project. I didn't understand very well how to create this database, he didn't detailed the process. Follow what he says:

" Now that we have a model, we will need to create a table in our database that matches it. We will use Django to generate a migration for us and then run the migration to create a table for our movie model.
While Django can create and run migrations for our Django apps, it will not create the database and database user for our Django project. To create the database and user, we have to connect to the server using an administrator's account. Once we've connected we can create the database and user by executing the following SQL:"

```
CREATE DATABASE mymdb;
CREATE USER mymdb;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mymdb to "mymdb";
ALTER USER mymdb PASSWORD 'development';
ALTER USER mymdb CREATEDB;
```

I don't know where to type this line of code. Shell? I know his book uses the PostgreSQL database.

Thank you,

Comment: Depends on the database you would like to use. But for example, you can run a docker image of your desired DB, if you want to use Postgresql, you can easily follow this manual: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#connect-the-database

Comment: You'd be better off just using PGAdmin so you don't have to worry about learning Postgres commands too (for now)

Comment: The beginning of the book I have to change some settings in DATABASE. DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mymdb',
        'USER': 'mymdb',
        'PASSWORD': 'development',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432'

Answer (score 0):

To execute commands on the database, you need some kind of client. If you have access to the database server bash, you can use the command line client `psql`.

For clients with a GUI, pgadmin is the most common. On the interface, you are able to open a window, in which you can insert the SQL commands.